# Link array of JsonNodes to ArrayNode

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an `ArrayNode` that looks like this:

```
[{
    "A": "a",
    "B": "b",
    "C": "c"
}]
```

I'd like to manually add an array of `JsonNode`s :

```
[{
    "A": "a",
    "B": "b",
    "C": "c",
    "D": [{
            "D": "d",
            "e": "e"
         }]
}]
```

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
final ObjectNode jsonNode = nodeFactory.objectNode();
jsonNode.set(name) // name == "D", but method prototype is set(string, JsonNode)
arrayNode.add(jsonNode);
```

Problem is the `set` method must take a `JsonNode` as second parameter. I just want to create the "D" key in order to link the other JsonNodes thereafter. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the member nodes before you push the value into the `ObjectNode`. It is just keeping the keys/values in a `Map` behind the scenes.

```
ObjectNode node = nodeFactory.objectNode();
node.set("D", buildArrayNode());
...

private ArrayNode buildArrayNode() {
    // build your node here
    ArrayNode arrayNode = nodeFactory.arrayNode();
    arrayNode.add(...);
}
```